# Error while creating table with an auto increment column

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a table with `one auto increment and one default column`, but mysql is throwing
 `"Incorrect table Definition; there can only be one auto column and it should be defined as key"`
the table am using is shown below:

```
create table dummy 
(invno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 candidate varchar(50) default '000',
client varchar(20) );
```

thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is already giving you the answer, your auto increment must be a key.

So the solution is:

```
create table dummy (invno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, candidate varchar(50) default '000', client varchar(20) );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE  dummy
(
 invno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 candidate varchar(50)  default '000',
 client  varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (invno)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only define a column as AUTO_INCREMENT.
make it as PRIMARY KEY.

```
create table dummy 
(invno int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, candidate varchar(50) default '000', client varchar(20) );
```